# Android ScaleAnimation, how to use it to make items smaller, not bigger

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using ScaleAnimation. I I would like to double the sizeof my item, it's easy:

```
ScaleAnimation  setSizeForTop = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 2);
```

and then:

```
top.startAnimation(setSizeForTop);
```

but once i have a big item (hiz size x2), how to make it smaller, not to doble as before but to divide the animation size by 2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try `setSizeForTop = new ScaleAnimation(1, .5f, 1, .5f);`
 ?

Comment: I have one more litle question, when i am doint the first operation which consist to make bigger my item with new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 2);, my item is moving, how can i stop this movement.

Comment: what does you mean by moving? is the view translating?

Comment: I will post a new question with this, it is a litle complicated to explain it in comments. I wil post the link in few minutes.

Comment: Here is the link of the auestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705452/android-scaleanimation-and-translateanimation-how-to-avoid-scaleanimation-movem

Answer (score 0):

this will stop it moving

ScaleAnimation(1, 1.5f, 1, 1.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)