# Android ScaleAnimation and TranslateAnimation, how to avoid ScaleAnimation movement

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an AnimationSet with inside a ScaleAnimation and a TranslateAnimation like this:

TranslateAnimation:

```
TranslateAnimation goTopFromRight =
        new TranslateAnimation(0, -(right.getLeft()-top.getLeft()),
                               0,-(right.getTop()-top.getTop()));
```

ScaleAnimation:

```
ScaleAnimation =  setSizeForTop = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 2);
```

and AnimationSet:

```
bringToLeftFromTopAnimationSet  = new AnimationSet(true);
bringToTopFromRightAnimationSet.addAnimation(goTopFromRight);
bringToTopFromRightAnimationSet.addAnimation(setSizeForTop);
```

The problem is that when i try to use only the ScaleAnimation, my item goes to the position i want, but whe I am using the ScaleAnimation with the TranslateAnimation in the AnimationSet, my item translates more than i need, as if ScaleAnimation introduces some supplementary movements abd I don't know how to delete them.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the ScaleAnimation movement when using the ScaleAnimation and TranslateAnimation, you have to multiply the TranslateAnimation parametres with those from ScaleAnimation like this:

```
TranslateAnimation goRightFromTop;
ScaleAnimation sizeNotUp;

goRightFromTop  = new TranslateAnimation(0,(-( invisibleCenterImageView.getLeft() - imageViewRight.getLeft() ))*(1/0.6667f), 0, (-( invisibleCenterImageView.getTop() - imageViewRight.getTop()))*(1/0.6667f)); 
sizeNotUp       = new ScaleAnimation(1,0.6667f,1,0.6667f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
```

And then, surprise you deleted the ScaleAnimation movement.

Answer (score 5):

The correct solution is to change order of animations. Scale must go first:

```
bringToTopFromRightAnimationSet.addAnimation(setSizeForTop);
bringToTopFromRightAnimationSet.addAnimation(goTopFromRight);
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember having weird problems with nested animations as well.
Have you tried setting the pivot point manually? See `public ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, float pivotX, float pivotY)` from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html for it.
It could work.

Comment: Thank you for tha answer @ShadowMare and sorry for the late replay. In fact, I don't understand what are the float pivotX and float pivotY.

Comment: sorry, didnt notice the comment. I am quite sure you already figured out that both pivot values are the "anchor" point of the animation.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowMare, in fact, to avoid the muvement, we have to multiply the TranslateAnimation by the ScaleAnimation parametres.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add a container outside your view, and apply the scale animation to your view while applying translate animation to the container.
Then you can make more complex animation even via XML~